# OpenCV Unsharp Mask Java Implementation

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, implementation

I'm trying to implement this Unsharp Mask algorithm that I found at [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details&gsc.tab=0)

Edit: This is the algorithm.

```
Mat blurred; double sigma = 1, threshold = 5, amount = 1;
GaussianBlur(img, blurred, Size(), sigma, sigma);
Mat lowContrastMask = abs(img - blurred) < threshold;
Mat sharpened = img*(1+amount) + blurred*(-amount);
img.copyTo(sharpened, lowContrastMask);
```

I stuck here:

```
//  Mat lowContrastMask = abs(img - blurred) < threshold;

    Mat lowContrastMask = new Mat();
    Core.absdiff(source, destination, lowContrastMask);
```

I don't know how to implement "< threshold" part. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your link doesn't point to any algorithm, just OpenCV doc

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `threshold`:

```
Imgproc.threshold(lowContrastMask, lowContrastMask, 0, thresh, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Comment: It doesn't give any error, but results are not so good. I guess there are multiple mistakes in my algorithm.